# Javascript Sequence of Function Example

Tags: javascript, function, console

```
function makeMultiplier(multiplier) {
  var myFunc = function (x) {
    return multiplier * x;
  };

  return myFunc;
}

var multiplyBy3 = makeMultiplier(3);
console.log(multiplyBy3(10));
```

So I got this example from an online course, the console prints: **30**

I don't exactly understand how the value 30 was obtained, below is what I think is how it is executed, but please do correct me if false.

1. I assume first that the value of *multiplier* becomes 3, then the function *makeMultiplier* returns 3 * X.
2. From here, by assigning var *multiplyBy3* = *makeMultiplier*(3), essentially *multiplyBy3* is now a function that returns 3 * X.
3. Therefore when 10 is plugged in, it returns 3 * 10 = 30.

Comment: Yes, `makeMultiplier(3)` does return a function. (That it is assigned to a variable isn't strictly necessary)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you are correct, remember that [functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions) can be passed around to and from variables and other functions.

- `makeMultiplier` returns a reference to a [function closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures), it doesn't execute it yet.
- `var multiplyBy3 = makeMultiplier(3);` Puts the value 3 into the closure function, and returns a reference to it (still doesn't execute it yet).

At this stage we have:

```
function multiplyBy3(x) {
    return 3 * x;
}

console.log(multiplyBy3(10));
```

- `multiplyBy3(10)` calls the reference to the closure function and passes in 10.

Answer (score 1):

The example you posted is also referred to as "[currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying)". Here's [another javascript example of currying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36314/what-is-currying/36321#36321).

I do recommend that you get in the habit of using ES6 syntax. Your example rewritten in ES6:

```
const makeMultiplier = multiplier => x => multiplier * x;
const multiplyBy3 = makeMultiplier(3);
console.log( multiplyBy3(10) ); // 30
```

or

```
console.log( makeMultiplier(3)(10) ); //30
```

Comment: It's a *curried function*, yes, but there's no currying happening in the example.

Answer (score 0):

Correct. This is what is known as a 'closure' (a function that returns another function that has access to the scope of the parent function.